# Dockerfile, /bin/sh: ...... not found AlpineLinux

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

```
FROM alpine:latest
MAINTAINER Xxxxxxx Yyyyyyyy <my e-mail>
RUN apk  update && apk upgrade apk bash && \
apk add nano && \
apk add mc && \
apk add python-dev && \
apk add python && \
apk add python3-dev && \
apk add python3 && \
apk add git && \
apk add py-pip && \
apk add openssl && \
```

######## здесь я хочу вставить код, который обновит **PIP** в момент создания образа

```
CMD ['/usr/bin/pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'pip']
```

но как бы я не менял код, у меня всегда возникает ошибка : ***/bin/sh: ..........  : not found***

подскажите как правильно создать Dockerfile? Чтобы обновление до последней версии PIP произошло в момент создания образа

Comment: Для «в момент создания» вам нужен RUN, а не CMD

Comment: а можно вариант кода?

Спасибо!!

Comment: Тоже самое пишете после RUN... типо RUN pip upgrade

Comment: Но ошибка не в этом, а в кавычках. Сам с такой проблемой сталкивался. Вместо одинарной (') надо ставить двойную (")

Comment: смена кавычек результат не меняет

Comment: У вас лишний && \  в последней строчке. Стоит подучить синтаксис dockerfile что бы понимать что и зачем в нём написано.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!!
А можно прямо написать эти пару строк, а то я уже кучу комбинаций испробовал - всё равно ошибки

Comment: ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
 RUN (missing):
    required by: world[RUN]
  [pip (missing):
    required by: world[[pip]
  install, (missing):
    required by: world[install,]
  pip] (missing):
    required by: world[pip]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add bash \
            nano \
            mc \
            python-dev \
            python \
            python3-dev \
            python3 \
            git \
            py-pip \
            openssl
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
```

`pip` будет обновлен до последней версии, или сразу использовать `python:alpine` в нем уже будет актуальная версия.

Comment: не хотелось использовать что-то готовое, хотелось самому собрать всё с нуля.
Огромноне спасибо!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

CMD это команда которая исполняется в процессе работы контейнера, а не в процессе сборки. Для апгрейда pip, добавьте команду в существующий слой(RUN) или добавьте новый.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!
А можно пример кода показать, как это. сделать?
И можно ли в новый слой несколько разных апгрейдов делать?
Спасибо!!!!

Comment: RUN ['/usr/bin/pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'pip']

пробую вот так, но всё равно в ответ при компиляции  ***/bin/sh: RUN: not*** found

Comment: @SpeedyGonzales Как вам верно написали, в ответе выше, квадратные скобки здесь совершенно излишни.